# Product of imaginary numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

A book stated that $\sqrt{-a}•\sqrt{-b} = -\sqrt{ab}$ 
 where, *a* and *b* are positive real numbers. I know the proof of the above equation but why isn't this $\sqrt{-a}•\sqrt{-b} = \sqrt{ab}$. It also stated that this equality $\sqrt{a}•\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$ is true only when either of *a* and *b* are positive or zero but is false when *a* and *b* are negative, but why?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: $\sqrt{-a}=i\sqrt{a}$, for $a\geq 0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is $\sqrt{-x}*\sqrt{-x}=-x?$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362654/why-is-sqrt-x-sqrt-x-x). See also [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times {-1}} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12)

Answer (score 0):

If we define $\sqrt{-a} = i\sqrt{a}$ for positive $a,$ then
$$\sqrt{-a}\sqrt{-b} = i\sqrt{a}i\sqrt{b} = -\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = -\sqrt{ab}$$ where we multiplied the i's together to get -1.

It is not true that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$ for negative a and b, because that would imply $\sqrt{-a}\sqrt{-b} = \sqrt{ab}$ for positive a and b, which we just showed was false.

I should add that there's a bit of ambiguity in how you define *the* square root of a negative number (remember, there's always two roots), but under the convention I gave, that's what you get.

Answer (score 0):

So it's weird but you gotta evaluate underneath the radical first. In PEDMAS we have exponents before multiplications and square roots are exponents so $\sqrt {-a} \cdot \sqrt {-b}= i\sqrt a\cdot i\sqrt b=-\sqrt {ab}$